# How to ignore behaviorRelay element removal on RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm observing a BehaviorRelay and I want to subscribe only when the number of items increase. I tried **distinct/dinstinctUntilChanged** but it does not suit my needs because it will skip too much or too few times.

```
behaviorRelay
  .compactMap { $0?.items }
  .subscribe(onNext: { elements in
      print("items has one more element.")
  }).disposed(by: bag)
```

`var behaviorRelay = BehaviorRelay<[Car]?>(value: [])`

```
class Car {
  var items: [Any] // whatever... just an example.
}
```

Comment: If the array has 5 items in it, then one is removed, then one added, does that count, or would you only want to be notified if the array goes to 6 items?

Comment: @DanielT. it counts for sure. The whole point is to ignore reducing but never appending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, use `map` to map from array to number (of elements):

```swift
.map { $0?.count ?? 0 } // return 0 if array is nil
```

Than use `scan`, to retrieve both current and previous element, like this:

```swift
.scan((0, 0)) { previousPairOfValues, newValue in
    return (previousPairOfValues.1, newValue) // create new pair from newValue and second item of previous pair
}
```

Then use `filter`, to only pass increasing values:

```swift
.filter { $0.1 > $0.0 } // newer value greater than older value
```

Than map it back to the latest value:

```swift
.map { $0.1 }
```

Putting all together:

```swift
behaviorRelay
  .compactMap { $0?.items }
  .map { $0?.count ?? 0 } // return 0 if array is nil
  .scan((0, 0)) { previousPairOfValues, newValue in
    return (previousPairOfValues.1, newValue) // create new pair from newValue and second item of previous pair
  }
  .filter { $0.1 > $0.0 } // newer value greater than older value
  .map { $0.1 }
  .subscribe(onNext: { elementCount in
      print("items has one more element.")
      print("there are \(elementCount) items now")
  }).disposed(by: bag)
```